# Matlab filter not compatible with Python lfilter

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, filter, scipy

Good day,

I have been fiddling around porting matlab code to python and I ran into this weird issue. I googled around a bit but found no information that indicates I am doing something wrong.

The core of the issue is Matlab's filter(b, a, data) (which is built-in into matlab) is generating a different output when comparing to Python's scipy.signal.lfilter

This is the issue, performed on an arbitrary pink noise signal

I have filter coefficients given to me by a third party and they are as follows:

```
a0 = 1
a1 = -1.69065929318241
a2 = 0.73248077421585
b0 = 1.53512485958697
b1 = -2.69169618940638
b2 = 1.19839281085285
```

In matlab I initialize the numerator/denominator as follows:

```
a = [a0 a1 a2];
b = [b0 b1 b2];
```

In python I do it like this:

```
a = np.array([a0, a1, a2])
b = np.array([b0, b1, b2])
```

After reading in the signal in both matlab/python I print out the first 15 samples to make sure that you guys know the input is the same

Matlab:

```
   0.061920166015625
  -0.050170898437500
  -0.117370605468750
  -0.065979003906250
  -0.013854980468750
  -0.042663574218750
   0.107452392578125
  -0.044006347656250
   0.115112304687500
  -0.043457031250000
  -0.028778076171875
  -0.128234863281250
   0.045227050781250
  -0.091796875000000
   0.315063476562500
```

Python:

```
[[ 0.06192017]
 [-0.0501709 ]
 [-0.11737061]
 [-0.065979  ]
 [-0.01385498]
 [-0.04266357]
 [ 0.10745239]
 [-0.04400635]
 [ 0.1151123 ]
 [-0.04345703]
 [-0.02877808]
 [-0.12823486]
 [ 0.04522705]
 [-0.09179688]]
```

then I call the filter functions

Matlab:

```
out = filter(b,a,data);
out(1:15)

ans =

   0.095055186160338
  -0.082982934483728
  -0.180851002009017
  -0.090458464750796
  -0.004794343459254
  -0.049115794227541
   0.183660200687651
  -0.061428954478571
   0.185550654888710
  -0.070597744360580
  -0.044524076275862
  -0.195036835228527
   0.082983215098531
  -0.133175807494538
   0.499012320158226
```

Python:

```
out = lfilter(b,a,data)
print out[0:14]

[[ 0.09505519]
 [-0.07701859]
 [-0.18017853]
 [-0.10128601]
 [-0.02126912]
 [-0.06549391]
 [ 0.16495284]
 [-0.06755524]
 [ 0.17671176]
 [-0.06671197]
 [-0.04417794]
 [-0.19685653]
 [ 0.06942917]
 [-0.14091966]]
```

Extra info:

Matlab R2012a

2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] -> python

1.6.2 -> numpy

My question is this:
Am I doing something wrong or did I just find a bug in an essential and basic function in the scipy package?

King regards,

K

EDIT: below in comments it was suggest to feed it with an impulse (I kept the coeffs)
Matlab:

```
   1.535124676585826
  -0.096323067867721
  -0.088906133468550
  -0.079755185442926
  -0.069716811972987
  -0.059448236072219
  -0.049440488368964
  -0.040042331136521
  -0.031483732058538
  -0.023898026476545
  -0.017342192117849
  -0.011814893332425
  -0.007272136901341
  -0.003640523618135
  -0.000828184619352
```

Python:

```
[[ 1.53512468]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.        ]]
```

There is definitely something going wrong here, this doesn't look like a filter at all...

Comment: Numpy isn't Matlab, perhaps they're doing different things (given that they don't claim to be equivalent)?

Comment: The documentation of both functions implies that they should do the same thing. They are both direct form II transposed implementations

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/filter.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#scipy.signal.lfilter

Comment: Hmmm... the math is the same for Matlab (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#f83-1015962) and Scipy (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#scipy.signal.lfilter).  The difference is too big to be rounding errors, or float vs double.  What if you feed it a simple impulse signal (all zeros except a single 1.0) and have a and b be just as simple - all zeros except a single 1 (note that a0 has to be 1)?  Real simple test cases might reveal something.

Comment: Check your code.  With numpy 1.7.1 and scipy 0.12.0, and with numpy 1.6.1 and scipy 0.10.1, I get almost exactly the same results as your matlab output. (The last digit of the last output value is different.)   For x, I used the input data that you show labeled "Matlab:", not what you show under "Python:".

Comment: I just typed your example into both scipy and octave (no matlab here). Got the same results in both, same as your matlab.  You have a buggy numpy or scipy!

Comment: Any tips to quickly verify my versions and stuff? I'm really new to python and since I like eclipse, I use pyDev, an eclipse python tool

Comment: Apparently you used the truncated data shown under "Python:" in your Python code using lfilter. If I use *that* data, my output matches your Python output.  With different inputs, of course you get different outputs.

Comment: Okay, multiple people are getting good signals, agreement between scipy and matlab/octave.  I have scipy 0.9.0, and it appears good.  What do you get with scipy.__version__ ?

Comment: Python 2.7 | numpy 1.6.1 | scipy 0.11.0

I'm uninstalling everything python related as we speak, to reinstall it from scratch. I'm on windows though - this shouldn't matter right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a bug. Matlab's `filter` operates on the *first* dimension of the array, while `scipy.signal.lfilter` by default operates on the the *last* dimension.

From your question I see that your `data` array has a second dimension (perhaps empty?). When you use `lfilter` it defaults to `axis=-1`, which will give the answer you got for python. If you want the same behaviour of matlab you need to specify the first axis or squeeze the array (if the second dimension has a size of 1):

```
out = lfilter(b, a, data, axis=0)
out = lfilter(b, a, np.squeeze(data))
```

Both of these return the following:

```
[ 0.09505519
 -0.08298293
 -0.180851
 -0.09045846
 -0.00479434
 -0.04911579
  0.1836602
 -0.06142895
  0.18555065
 -0.07059774
 -0.04452408
 -0.19503684
  0.08298322
 -0.13317581
  0.49901232]
```

Comment: Great answer! It explains why the result of the lfilter can be all zeros (the last dimension may be empty)