# Matlab filter with Python lfilter ValueError object of too small depth

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, filtering

I want to filter a signal in Python, inspired by Matlab code. Matlab has the function [`filter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html;jsessionid=3ed056774c1ce4c29298133f8920), which is supposed to be similar to [`scipy.signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) (from the question: [Matlab filter() with SciPy lfilter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922657/matlab-filter-with-scipy-lfilter)). However, I'm still getting a `ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array`.

## Matlab code (executed in Octave):

```
% Matlab
x = [1.0485e-04  -2.4193e-04  -3.0078e-04  1.5750e-03  -1.9698e-03  1.3902e-04  2.7568e-03  -3.8059e-03  2.0123e-03  3.3257e-03]
xfilt = filter(1, [1 -0.992217938], x);
disp(xfilt);

% output
1.0485e-04  -1.3790e-04  -4.3760e-04   1.1408e-03  -8.3788e-04  -6.9233e-04   2.0699e-03  -1.7522e-03   2.7378e-04   3.5974e-03
```

## Python:

```
# Python
from scipy.signal import lfilter

x = np.array([1.0485e-04, -2.4193e-04, -3.0078e-04, 1.5750e-03, -1.9698e-03, 1.3902e-04, 2.7568e-03, -3.8059e-03, 2.0123e-03, 3.3257e-03])
lfilter(1, np.array([1, -0.992217938]), x, axis=0)
```

Which result in the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-d5c23d362b45> in <module>
      1 x = np.array([1.0485e-04, -2.4193e-04, -3.0078e-04, 1.5750e-03, -1.9698e-03, 1.3902e-04, 2.7568e-03, -3.8059e-03, 2.0123e-03, 3.3257e-03])
----> 2 print(lfilter(1, np.array([1, -0.992217938]), x, axis=0))

~/anaconda3/envs/*env*/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py in lfilter(b, a, x, axis, zi)
   1378     else:
   1379         if zi is None:
-> 1380             return sigtools._linear_filter(b, a, x, axis)
   1381         else:
   1382             return sigtools._linear_filter(b, a, x, axis, zi)

ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

## System

- Python: 3.6.8
- Scipy: 1.2.0

## Tried

Based on the question " [Matlab filter not compatible with Python lfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936558/matlab-filter-not-compatible-with-python-lfilter) " I've tried to add `axis=0` to `lfilter`, but I still got the ValueError.

## Question

How to do the Matlab code in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciPy's `lfilter` expects the `b` argument to be a 1-d array (or "array-like", e.g. a list), not a scalar.  For example,

```
lfilter([1], np.array([1, -0.992217938]), x, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you. The output in Python is identical to the Matlab output.